# Myeclipse for spring Limitations

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, myeclipse

What are the limitations in Myeclipse's trial version for spring? can I create a non commercial app with it?
it is very practical to generate a crud application and then to modify it until you get to the results, I am afraid that the fact that Myeclipse is going to stop my program after few days or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no restrictions with the trial license for any MyEclipse edition. During the trial period (30 days), MyEclipse for Spring will work exactly the way it does with a full license. The license applies only to MyEclipse, not to any applications you create with MyEclipse. Of course, after 30 days, you will no longer be able to maintain any applications on MyEclipse, until you buy a full license, but the applications themselves will be unaffected.